# ProgressBar не правильно отражает выполнение потока

Tags: c#, wpf

Приложение на WPF с ProgressBar-ом, в котором должно отражатся выполнение потока. Тем не менее, процесс заполнения ProgressBar-a сразу 100%, хотя этого не должно быть.

Код запуска события, через который отражается процесс загрузки в Progressbar-e:

```
private async void Hyperlink_Download(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextBoxFilePath.Text != "")
        {
            try
            {
                var progress = new Progress<int>(value => pBar.Value = value);
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                    {
                        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
                            pars.SaveImage(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri, TextBoxFilePath.Text);
                        });
                        pBar.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => pBar.Value = i, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                message.ShowError(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            message.ShowMessage("Введите путь для сохранения файлов");
        }
    }
```

И сам метод:

```
       public async Task SaveImage(string imageUrl, string pathFile)
       {
          string result = imageUrl.Substring(imageUrl.IndexOf("src/") + 14);

           string fileName = pathFile + @"\" + result;

           using (WebClient webclient = new WebClient())
           {
              await Task.Run(() => webclient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(imageUrl), fileName));
           }
        }
```

Прошу помощи. Спасибо.

Comment: ну, у вас тут много чего, глаза разбегаются, с чего бы начать

Comment: вот эта конструкция `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { pars.SaveImage(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri, TextBoxFilePath.Text); });` - она что делает? Она дождется разве окончания асинхронного метода?

Comment: вот это `var progress = new Progress<int>(value => pBar.Value = value);` для чего вообще?

Comment: вот этот метод `Hyperlink_Download` из какого потока запускается?

Comment: `await Task.Run(() => webclient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(imageUrl), fileName));` для чего здесь `Task.Run` ?

Comment: ну и ваши манипуляции с извлечением `reversedUrl` мне совсем непонятны. Вы умеете работать со `string.IndexOf` и `string.Substring`? Похоже, вам именно это и нужно.

Comment: вот этот цикл `for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)` - он же одно и то же делает, зачем он нужен вообще?

Comment: @tym32167 Dispatcher.Invoke - триггер метода через событие. var progress - лишний копипаст. Реализация SaveImage топорная, не думаю, что в этом проблема

Comment: никакой это не триггер, вы что то путаете. Если вам нужно только понять где проблема, то она тут `Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>{pars.SaveImage(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri, TextBoxFilePath.Text); });` - вы не ждете окончания своей асинхронной функции. Хотите, чтобы оно заработало, пишите `await Dispatcher.Invoke(() => pars.SaveImage(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri, TextBoxFilePath.Text));`, но это не отменяет все остальные вопросы к вашему коду.

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо за советы насчет IndexOf и Substring. Помучаю потоки, т.к. плаваю в этом вопросе.